# Session variable is not persisting when create action is started Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a form that requires I send an id to a form object, and then create that form using the Id that I passed. I started the object's id in a session variable, the form initializes without issue. But, it fails during the create action. As if I never assigned the id of the object....How can I persist the id while the form is processing the create action?

link to form action

```
   <%= link_to 'New Contract', new_provider_contract_path(provider_form_id: provider.id), class: 'remove-text-decoration button' %>


 # GET /provider_contracts/new
  def new
    @provider = ProviderForm.find(params[:provider_form_id])
    session[:provider_form_id] = @provider
    @provider_contract = @provider.provider_contracts.build(provider_form: session[:provider_form_id])
    @provider_contract.build_contract_profile
    @provider_contract.build_contract_information
    @provider_contract.build_contract_term
    @provider_contract.build_contract_additional_term
    @provider_contract.contract_comments.build

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to provider_contracts_path, notice: 'The provider has been removed or has not been selected'
  end

 # POST /provider_contracts
  # POST /provider_contracts.json
  def create
   @provider_contract = ProviderContract.new(provider_contract_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @provider_contract.save
        format.html { redirect_to @provider_contract, notice: 'Provider contract was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @provider_contract }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @provider_contract.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

provider_contracts_controller

```
 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def provider_contract_params
    params.require(:provider_contract).permit( :provider_form_id,
        ProviderContract.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym),
                                              ProviderForm.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym),
                                              contract_to_facility_connections_attributes: ContractToFacilityConnection.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_reward_attributes: ContractReward.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_profile_attributes: ContractProfile.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy, :contract_document),
                                              contract_information_attributes: ContractInformation.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_term_attributes: ContractTerm.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_term_fees_attributes: ContractTermFee.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_term_stipends_attributes: ContractTermStipend.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_additional_term_attributes: ContractAdditionalTerm.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_term_call_types_attributes: ContractTermCallType.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy),
                                              contract_comments_attributes: ContractComment.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy, user: current_user))
  end
```

form errors

```
ProviderForm must exist!
```

routes.rb

```
resources :provider_contracts
```

COMPLETE LOGS

```
Started POST "/provider_contracts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-14 14:44:39 -0500
Processing by ProviderContractsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Pm0kHge1RXSVDwZV9X7AsSam0B+EHjIfwHwBfXrJ9Dn2fp5to5u9RCa5xsA==", "provider_contract"=>{"contract_to_facility_connections_attributes"=>{"1573760656135"=>{"facility_id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "status"=>"LOCUM", "is_confidential"=>"", "contract_profile_attributes"=>{"contract_file_type"=>"CV", "provider_specialty"=>"", "contract_class"=>"", "engaget"=>"", "comment"=>""}, "contract_information_attributes"=>{"contract_stage"=>"Submitted for Approval", "commencement_date(1i)"=>"2019", "commencement_date(2i)"=>"11", "commencement_date(3i)"=>"14", "assigned_to"=>"", "is_commencement_date_unknown"=>"0", "process_owner"=>"", "existing_or_returning"=>"", "action_requested"=>"", "background_check_status"=>"", "reason_for_contract_request"=>"", "watermark"=>"", "deadline_date(1i)"=>"2019", "deadline_date(2i)"=>"11", "deadline_date(3i)"=>"14", "priority"=>""}, "contract_term_attributes"=>{"frequency_status"=>"Daily", "compensation_amount"=>"", "time_off_status"=>"", "optional_time_off"=>"", "optional_time_off_count"=>"", "optional_time_off_days"=>"", "contracted_hours_amount"=>"", "overtime_excess"=>""}, "contract_additional_term_attributes"=>{"malpractice_provider"=>"Employer/Company", "malpractice_cost"=>"", "malpractice_limits"=>"", "health_insurance_eligibility"=>"", "health_insurance_cost"=>"", "workers_comp"=>"", "initial_term_amount"=>"", "initial_term_time_length"=>"", "renewal_term_amount"=>"", "renewal_term_time_length"=>"", "termination_notice_amount"=>"", "termination_notice_time_length"=>"", "non_renewal_notice_amount"=>"", "renewal_notice_time_length"=>"", "comment"=>""}, "provider_form"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save Contract"}
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/provider_contracts_controller.rb:95:in `provider_contract_params'
Unpermitted parameter: :provider_form
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/provider_contracts_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
  Facility Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities" WHERE "facilities"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/provider_contracts_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/provider_contracts_controller.rb:40:in `block in create'
  Rendering provider_contracts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Facility Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities"
  ↳ app/views/provider_contracts/_contract_to_facility_connection_fields.html.erb:2
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_to_facility_connection_fields.html.erb (Duration: 37.7ms | Allocations: 4269)
  CACHE Facility Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "facilities".* FROM "facilities"
  ↳ app/views/provider_contracts/_contract_to_facility_connection_fields.html.erb:2
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_to_facility_connection_fields.html.erb (Duration: 63.3ms | Allocations: 4026)
  Rendered provider_contracts/partials/_contract_profile.html.erb (Duration: 141.8ms | Allocations: 10810)
  Rendered provider_contracts/partials/_contract_information.html.erb (Duration: 113.1ms | Allocations: 15419)
  Rendered provider_contracts/partials/_contract_term.html.erb (Duration: 105.4ms | Allocations: 12074)
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_term_fee_fields.html.erb (Duration: 74.0ms | Allocations: 9916)
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_reward_fields.html.erb (Duration: 74.1ms | Allocations: 9886)
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_term_stipend_fields.html.erb (Duration: 46.5ms | Allocations: 11007)
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_term_call_type_fields.html.erb (Duration: 50.2ms | Allocations: 13248)
  Rendered provider_contracts/_contract_additional_term.html.erb (Duration: 48.9ms | Allocations: 14852)
  Rendered provider_contracts/_form.html.erb (Duration: 920.8ms | Allocations: 112376)
  Rendered provider_contracts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 921.3ms | Allocations: 112442)
  Rendered navbars/_user_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 2.1ms | Allocations: 745)
  Rendered flash_messages/_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 21)
Completed 200 OK in 1022ms (Views: 988.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms | Allocations: 157626)
```

Comment: Does the error occur after clicking the link? Can you show your routes for provider_contract?

Comment: It occurs when I'm in the create action. Even though the form loads in the new action.

Comment: I see this in the server logs. I will try again shortly.  Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy
Unpermitted parameter: :provider_form

Comment: I added the provider_form object to the whitelist and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

its just a guess but couldn't it be the `@provider.id` in your form in `provider_form_id: provider.id`? `<%= link_to 'New Contract', new_provider_contract_path(provider_form_id: provider.id), class: 'remove-text-decoration button' %>`
Also you might want to add

```
def set_provider  
@provider = ProviderForm.find(params[:provider_form_id]) 
end
```

at the private section along wiht permitted_params in your provider_contracts_controller.rb and call at the very begginnig of the controller `before_action :set_provider, only: %i[create]` Worth a try if you didn't have it in the controller yet.

Comment: Couldn't find ProviderForm without an ID. I need to somehow get the id to the create method. I will try to pass the session variable to it

Comment: Doesn't work. the session variable is passing a hash to the find method.

Comment: On which view page exactly your form is located. Providers#index or Providers#show?

Comment: Why I am asking this is because if we are on the Providers#index page you do need to have some sort of a select form or a checkbox to explicitly select one provider so that provider_id can be passed over to the params hash.